# CartoCSS: Filter by json field

Tags: mapbox, cartocss

In a MapBox Studio project of mine, I have field values that are stored as JSON values.  My features all have attributes like:

```
id 48545756
meta {}
relations []
tags {"access":"forestry","highway":"track","source":"WRI;DIAF","start_date":"before2013-03-28"}
type way
```

I'm trying to filter by a key in the tags field.  Something like:

```
#layer['tags.access' = 'forestry']{ ... }
or
#layer['tags' = '{"access": "forestry"}']{ ... }
```

But of course MapBox Studio interprets the JSON as a string, not something that can be parsed.

Any thoughts on how to get around this?

*Why JSON as feature attribute values?*  MapBox's [uploads api](https://www.mapbox.com/developers/api/uploads/) provides a really good way to programmatically upload data to a MapBox account.  If you send a geojson file (rather than a mbtiles file), MapBox tiles it out with it's attributes as a json value in the 'tags' field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  While it doesn't look like it's possible to actually parse the json, MapBox Studio [supports regular expressions in filters](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/selectors/#regular-expression-filters):

```
#original {
  line-color: #F8842E;
  line-width: 0.8;
  [tags =~ '.*"access":"forestry".*']{
    line-width: 1.4;
  }
}
```